# SQL Server data patch for replacing 2 double quotes in between to single double quote

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am currently trying to do data patch.

Consider this example: every day, after nightly process is successful, I am getting borrower name somewhat different. If borrower name has single quote in between the string, I am getting value as ("").

For example, if the record has value `JAN E. O"BRIEN`, then every night, I am getting the result as `JAN E. O""BRIEN`.

I can update the previous data by simple update. But, every night, I am getting the same error. So, I would like to update my stored procedure logic with some Case Statement in order to handle such escape character situation.

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue in SQL Server? (P.S. I am using SQL Server 2014)

Comment: It would help to see the logic which is inserting that value.  or even an example if not the exact code which shows this problem occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a simple replace when you are retrieving the values.

Some think like:

```
Select Replace(FieldName ,'""','"') as FieldName from table..
```

I figure that another statement is updating every day the value inserting ("").

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to know how to handle the situation if there is no double quotes in Borrower name? Then, I want the data as is. So, could you please let me know how to handle such data. Is there any case statement should I need?

Comment: don't worry, if there are no double quotes the register is returned with no changes.